# Is it possible to integrate maps in Cytoscape.js?

Tags: maps, data-visualization, cytoscape.js

I am currently using cytoscapeJS to visualize a network but I would like to overlay the graph on a map and plot the nodes to specific locations.  The [Tokyo Railways Demo](http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/f64e811fc3311414e083/) is similar to what I have imagined but the background is black.

In a perfect world I could dynamically calculate the longitude and latitude from the node's address data (but I guess this would require cytoscape to have geocoding capabilities) and then plot that on a map.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do: http://xliberation.com/googlecharts/d3flights.html

Comment: I realized I can change the background image of the graph using css and then position the nodes where I want them to be and lock them so they cannot be dragged.

This is not a sufficient solution because the background image is fixed and zooming in and out changes the size of the graph...

Comment: This question is a duplicate with an existing answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756417/zoomable-background-for-cytoscape-js